# compilation error in visual studio linked with python26

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am getting an error running:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYTHON -DJCC_VER="2.13" -D_java_generics -IX:\Java16/include -IX:\Java16/include/win32 -Ibuild\_CMMCore -IC:\Python26\lib\site-packages\jcc\sources -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Python26\PC /Tpbuild\_CMMCore\CMMCore.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.6\Release\build\_CMMCore\CMMCore.obj /EHsc /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

The following:

```
c:\python26\include\pyconfig.h(233) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

I put C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include into PATH because it includes BaseTsd.h, but this didnt solve the problem. I dont think it has to do with the cases?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the PATH it's INCLUDE environment variable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: That worked! Many many thanks. But now I get a new error where jvm.lib is missing; I put the directory holding it into LIBPATH, but that didnt work. You wouldnt happen to know how to fix this, would you?

Comment: Hi, I used the SDK cmd shell and the directories are in the `%INCLUDE%` variable. But I still get the same error. Could you take a look at [my question here][1] please? Many thanks!
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691564/running-cython-in-windows-x64-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-ba

Comment: @PreetSangha what does this answer mean? What are you suggesting as a solution?

Comment: @PreetSangha What do you mean by the above?

Answer (score 0):

I copy missing ".h" header files to "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\include", and it works.