# Running Cython in Windows x64 - fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cython, python-extensions

I have been trying to install Cython for Python 2.7 on my Window 7 system. In particular, I prefer everything in 64 bits. (In case you wonder, I need Cython because Cython is one of the components I need for another package for some specialized numerical analysis. And x64 is potentially an advantage for storage of large data sets.)

So I downloaded the x64 Python 2.7 from the official website. Got Cython from [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython). The amd64 version for Python 2.7 of course. Before I installed, I added Python 2.7 into the registry with the `.reg` file found in [Joe DF's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652625/installing-setuptools-on-64-bit-windows/9131949#9131949). Afterwards, I installed the Visual C++ compiler from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=15336) (I don't think it works) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138) (but this one should). At this point, I have in my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin` directory all of `vcvars32.bat`, `vcvars64.bat`, `vcvars86_amd64.bat`, `vcvarsx86_ia64.bat`. I ran `vcvars64.bat` and there was no error message.

Subsequently, I followed [this page](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html) to create a "hello world" test file.

Then, I got this error.

```
...\Tests>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'hello' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

So I thought to myself: Well, Cython can't find that file because it does not exist. (I searched my whole harddrive for it.) So I copied `vcvars64.bat` from `...\VC\bin` to `\VC` and changed the name to `vcvarsall.bat`. Now vcvarsall error is gone. And ... naturally, a new error emerges.

```
...\Tests>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'hello' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nolog
o /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tchello.c /F
obuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hello.obj
hello.c
C:\Python27\include\pyconfig.h(227) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include fil
e: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64
\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

Now I have no idea how to proceed. What should I do? Your help is much appreciated.

(For clarity, I did try setting the compiler to Mingw32. But there are other errors. I am focusing on getting VC to work for now.)

---

EDIT: I tried using the SDK build environment CMD following the instructions on [this page](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html). I received the same error.

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558328/1805756) helps.

Comment: Hi SAM, I am aware of the variable `VS90COMNTOOLS`. Cython actually searches the VC directory first before going to `VS90COMNTOOLS`. And at least within the initial steps of building, Cython is able to locate the VC components as described in the question text. Thank you though.

Comment: have you checked (a) that the file is installed and where and (b) what the compiler is including using /showincludes and finally (c) verified that item is not hidden by a compiler directive? If you check the cl.exe help /? then you should be able to make is much much more verbose.

Comment: Hi Preet, I just found out neither `basetsd.h` or `windows.h` (another header file mentioned in the building C++ program page. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7kx322x.aspx) I wonder why though

Answer (score 53):

In case anyone is currently (2017) facing same error with visual C++ 2015 tools, launch setup again and also select windows 8.1 / 10 SDK depending upon your OS. This will fix `basestd.h` error.

If it is still not working, try launching build tools from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools.

Another alternative would be, just install anaconda 2 or 3 (64 bit if also you don't want memory errors). It contains all the important packages prebuilt: sklearn, matplotlib, scipy, numpy, pandas and even web development frameworks such as flask.

Comment: I've chosen win8.1 option on Windows 7. `pandas` has been built fine. Thanks.

Comment: This helped me with 32bit Windows 10 for installing Geemusic requirements.txt. Worked after I've installed Windows 10 SDK. Thanks ;)

Comment: Specifically installing the Windows headers option has helped!

Comment: 2018. I can't believe it but installing win 10 sdk 64 fixed my basestd.h issue and let me install scikit-image

Comment: 2021. I also can't believe it but installing win 10 sdk 64 fixed my basestd.h issue and let me install pybullet

Comment: 2022. I also can't believe it but installing win 10 sdk 64 fixed my basestd.h issue and let me install bottleneck

Comment: 2023. I also can't believe it but installing win 10 sdk 64 fixed my basestd.h issue and let me install pycryptodome

Comment: Years later - installing Windows 11 SDK worked perfect.  I encountered the "rc" issue described by daytony as well below, and the answer in the link also worked for me.

Answer (score 23):

I encountered this problem while trying to install `pandas` in 'develop' mode. I'm up & running now. My environment:

- Windows XP Pro x64 SP2
- [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net) 64bit 2.7.5.3 (Python 2.7.5.amd64) `<--` "registered" as system's python distro using WinPython Control Panel application

Problems encountered when running `python setup.py develop`:

- Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
- fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory ... exit code 2

Solution:

1. [Download](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279) and install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express.
2. [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138) and install Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. You will need only:

   - Developer Tools > Windows Headers and Libraries `<--` this gives you `basetsd.h`
   - Developer Tools > Visual C++ Compilers `<--` this gives you the 64-bit compilers
3. Copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars64.bat`
   to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvarsamd64.bat`. Observe the change in file name.
4. Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin` to `PATH`. This may not be required (I did so before re-installing the SDK w/ Headers & Libs; therefore, the necessity is unknown).

At this point, running `python setup.py develop` completed successfully and `python -c "import pandas; print pandas.__version__"` resulted in the git tag I expected.

**[EDIT]** Further reading:

- [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2817869/2946116)

  - [answer if you just want binaries to install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5983696/2946116)
  - [answer if you want to compile on x64 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18045219/2946116)
  - [answer about the file location/name change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19915585/2946116)
- [distutils issue 7511](http://bugs.python.org/issue7511)

Comment: Thats awesome. On a related note, do you know where\how to download Windows SDK for Windows 7 directly, without the web installer?

Comment: Sorry @LucasSoares I don't know where you might find that

Answer (score 22):

For those with Windows 10, download the SDK from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/) to fix the header file `basestd.h`.

I downloaded the .exe, installed and worked great. SDK was ~2.3GB.

**Note:** For those like me with 64-bit systems who got an additional error:

```
`LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158
```

There is a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215971/lnk1158-cannot-run-rc-exe-x64-visual-studio/) which solves the problem by placing the `rc.exe` file in the correct folder for your system.

Comment: Anaconda  + windows data center server - this is the only solution worked.  Here is the actual error: Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe
    geometry.c
    c:\programdata\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(222): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory

Comment: This was useful, but I also needed to copy the rcdll.dll file too, else I get a link.exe failed error statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563421/8195528

Comment: did not fix for me(

Comment: bloody hell that was annoying! glad it works now. Thanks buddy, many thanks for the link.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to run 'pip install twofish' and the error lead me here, which solved the problem!

Comment: Years later - and yes, perfect, this resolved this part of the issue for me as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For suggestion, you can try it for build cython 64 bit with setup.py

I'm using Anaconda for python distribution, Microsoft's Windopws SDK 7, and MSVC 12.0.

Firstly, I make library for my cuda function,
Second, I run python setup.py build_ext -i for make temp folder (you wil get error),
then compile Makefile below,

Mostly, I get this from setup.py when it is compile 32 bit app, then change it for compile 64 bit.

Makefile

```
CL_EXE      = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe"
LINK_EXE    = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe"

CL_FLAGS    = /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG /O2 /fp:fast
CL_INC      = -I. -I"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include" \
            -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include" -IC:\Users\name\Anaconda2\envs\py27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\name\Anaconda2\envs\py27\include -IC:\Users\name\Anaconda2\envs\py27\PC 

LINK_FLAGS      = /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /MACHINE:X64
LINK_LIBPATH    = "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\lib\x64" \
                    /LIBPATH:C:\Users\name\Anaconda2\envs\py27\libs \
                    /LIBPATH:C:\Users\name\Anaconda2\envs\py27\PCbuild\amd64 \
                    /LIBPATH:C:\Users\name\Anaconda2\envs\py27\PC\VS9.0\amd64 \
                    "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64" \
                    "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64"
LINK_LIB        = cuda_multiply4D.lib cudart.lib MSVCRT.lib kernel32.lib
LINK_EXPORT     = /EXPORT:initmy_cuda
LINK_OBJ        = build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\my_cuda.obj
LINK_OUT        = "/OUT:E:\my_cuda.pyd"
LINK_OTHER_CONF = /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\my_cuda.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\my_cuda.pyd.manifest 

all:
    $(CL_EXE) $(CL_FLAGS) $(CL_INC) /Tcmy_cuda.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\my_cuda.obj
    $(LINK_EXE) $(LINK_FLAGS) $(LINK_LIBPATH) $(LINK_LIB) $(LINK_EXPORT) $(LINK_OBJ) $(LINK_OUT) $(LINK_OTHER_CONF)
```

Note:

- MSVCRT.lib kernel32.lib are optional,
- /EXPORT:initmy_cuda is mandatory. Its format init%yourfilename_WO_Ext%
- "/OUT:E:\my_cuda.pyd" for determine your output location, its filename, and its extension.

Answer (score 1):

Add these to the visual studio installation directories to your Environment variables

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools
>
> hope it solves the issue.

Comment: While those directories did exist, it did not help for me

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by downloading and installing the latest Windows 10 SDK from this link:
https://software-download.microsoft.com/download/pr/19041.685.201201-2105.vb_release_svc_prod1_WindowsSDK.iso

but then another problem appeared with (cpython):

```
error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
```

which I could resolve by declaring additional pointers in

```
(...\python38\include\cpython\pystate.h)
```

I found these at line 77:

```
/* The exception currently being raised */
PyObject *curexc_type;
PyObject *curexc_value;
PyObject *curexc_traceback;
```

and I add the following just after them (without the first three letters "cur"):

```
/* The exception currently being raised */
PyObject *exc_type;
PyObject *exc_value;
PyObject *exc_traceback;
```

Comment: Having to rename internal details of the Python headers suggests to that you've messed something up. I'd guess you're using a 3-year old version of Cython that isn't compatible with Python 3.8. __Your "solution" is not a solution and you should expect your program to break in unexpected ways__