# Error with pip install imposm.parser, header files not found

Tags: python, c++

I am using python 2.7 and I am trying to `pip install imposm.parser`.

The first thing I did was to install protobuf with `pip install protobuf`. That installed version 2.6.1 in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\google`. Then I went [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/2.6.1-build2/) to  download `protoc-2.6.1-build2-windows-x86_32.exe` which I renamed to `protoc.exe` and placed in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\google` folder.

I then installed Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 from [here](http://aka.ms/vcpython27)

Finally, I executed `pip install imposm.parser` and this is the error I get:

> ```
> running build_ext
> building 'imposm.parser.pbf.OSMPBF' extension
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\imposm
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\imposm\parser
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\imposm\parser\pbf
> C:\Users\Shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -C:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tpimposm/parser/pbf/osm.cc Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\imposm/parser/pbf/osm.obj
>   osm.cc
> C:\Users\Shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
> c:\users\shiro\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jel4jl\imposm.parser\imposm\parser\pbf\osm.pb.h(9) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h': No such file or directory
> error: command '"C:\Users\Shiro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
> ```

**Edit**: The header header file saying that is missing is from `protobuf` which I just installed with `pip install protobuf`. The file missing is right here in the github [google/protobuf/stubs/common.h](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h) shouldn't it exist on my system since I installed with `pip` ? I don't understand...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691564/running-cython-in-windows-x64-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-ba). Years ago I experienced similar issues on Windows, and I went through a similar process with the solution in that link. Hope that helps.

Comment: Facing exactly the same problem here. 
Following in case anyone found a solution for this issue.