# Problem while installing package in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

i'm trying to install ivi package in pycharm, but received the following error:

```
 running build_ext
  building 'ivi.optimizations' extension
  optimizations.c
  C:\Users\tester\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include\pyconfig.h(205): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.
```

[Error log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yys8r.png)

[Full log](https://controlc.com/f2191bb5)

using windows 7, and python 3.8.10 is installed.

Comment: I would try upgrading your Visual Studio Build Tools (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42624713/4063622)