# error: while Building wheel for quadprog when installing trajectory-planning-helpers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I tried to install the module trajectory-planning-helpers with:

`pip install trajectory-planning-helpers`

I got this error

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:388: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1lt9e5l1\quadprog_6fa3226523604b288e1cc1c083587a6a\quadprog\quadprog.pyx
        tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
      Compiling quadprog/quadprog.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing quadprog/quadprog.pyx
      building 'quadprog' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\quadprog
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcquadprog/aind.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\quadprog/aind.obj
      aind.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcquadprog/daxpy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\quadprog/daxpy.obj
      daxpy.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcquadprog/ddot.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\quadprog/ddot.obj
      ddot.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcquadprog/dpofa.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\quadprog/dpofa.obj
      dpofa.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcquadprog/dscal.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\quadprog/dscal.obj
      dscal.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcquadprog/f2c_lite.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\quadprog/f2c_lite.obj
      f2c_lite.c
      quadprog/f2c_lite.c(48): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      quadprog/f2c_lite.c(134): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      quadprog/f2c_lite.c(182): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'integer', possible loss of data
      quadprog/f2c_lite.c(545): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iquadprog -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /EHsc /Tpquadprog/quadprog.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\quadprog/quadprog.obj
      quadprog.cpp
      C:\Python310\include\pyconfig.h(200): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

For context , my Python version is 3.10.10.

Things I tried:

1. Using a venv with python 3.10 and 3.11.
2. Downloading Microsoft SDK and friends (while the Python version is 3.11)

Comment: I am having this problem in Windows 11. I do not know about the writer of this question though.

Comment: If building wheels fails on your system, give its [wheel file](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/c6/47025182ec785856c4b7531a00fba177b405886bc5b338e199f70046aab3/trajectory_planning_helpers-0.79-py3-none-any.whl) a shot available from https://pypi.org/project/trajectory-planning-helpers/#files. It can be directly used with pip as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/13694848

Answer (score 0):

I just ditched windows and change to ubuntu. There's some problem but there is an easy solution for it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Visual C++ from here:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Because the last line seems to be the error

```
 C:\Python310\include\pyconfig.h(200): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
```

Also check if that still does not work https://stackoverflow.com/a/42624713/4063622