# visual studio 10.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe failed

Tags: python

I'm trying to install `scrapy` through pip. But it throws the below error.

```
visual studio 10.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe  failed with exit status 2
```

I'm running Windows 8 pc.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10773766/4869835) there is an answer but I don't know what he was actually trying to say..

I also did running `VCVARS32` command inside

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools
```

directory. But I still get the same error..

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/issues/detail?id=15

please have a look at patch here, this is a known issue.

Please bit careful on this patch though