# Python error: command '...\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, python-3.x, pip, mysql-python

I have some problems with python 3 module installing.
I'm trying to install mysql using pip :

```
python -m pip install mysql
```

for python 3.4.4 and here is the error I get:

`error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

here is a screenshot : [screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qamNK.png)

I had other problems with module installation before, and I solved those by installing Visual Studio C++ 2010

Btw, the installation of other modules are working just fine.

My specs :
Windows 10 x64

Python 3.4.4 x86

Comment: Please provide the full error message! Like here (maybe, it is related http://stackoverflow.com/q/10773732/1566267)

Comment: Run this file in the command line (admin): `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat` It will configure environment variables for using MSVC Compiler in command-line builds.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the full error message

Comment: "Run this file in the command line (admin): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat It will configure environment variables for using MSVC Compiler in command-line builds. "

This didn't solve my problem

Comment: Ok, then see that http://stackoverflow.com/q/26866147

Comment: None of the answers in this post worked either :/

Comment: Do you have Connector installed? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16619567/ Download it here and install: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/6.0.html#downloads It can be due to you have x64 Win, but mysql wants files to be in "Program Files (x86)" dir: `mklink /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include"` If won't help, try other answers from that post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1972259

Comment: Thanks a lot ! installing connector solved my problem !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution was provided in the comments.

Comment: @John_West please post as answer since it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Connector installed? (See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16619567))

Download it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/6.0.html#downloads) and install.

It can be due to you have x64 `Windows`, but `mysql` wants files to be in "Program Files (x86)" directory:

```
mklink /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include"
```

If won't help, try other answers from [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1972259)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I can solve it in PyCharm (version: 2019.2) as follow:

1. update the pip version in pycharm (at this time the latest version of pip is 20.0.2):

   1-1- Open project settings (File > Settings...) (preferences on Mac)

   1-2- Project > Project Interpreter

   1-3- Press the `+` button

   1-4- Type `pip` in the top search box

   1-5- In the lower right corner choose `specify version` and ensure using latest version

   1-6- press `Install Package` button

you can also find out the current version of pip through cmd in windows by this command:
`pip -V`
and then update pip by this command:
`pip install --upgrade pip`

2- Go to `File > Settings... > Project > Project:Interpreter` and update `pip` by clicking on `upgrade` button as the following picture (click on the small upward arrow at the right sidebar):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSsOH.png)

3- Like the first step, install latest version of `matplotlib` (at this time its latest version is 3.2)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install Pycocotools into my environment. I had the same error.

It got resolved by doing the following steps:

1. Install Visual Studio 2019 which gives the paths `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe`
2. Go to `Mask_RCNN`, type `cd Mask_RCNN`
3. In Anaconda Prompt, type `pip install pycocotools`
4. Install Clone of COCO, type `pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools^&subdirectory=PythonAPI`

You'll get the following: 
[image]

5. Open Jupyter notebook by typing `jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 0):

Go to this [site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and download whl file (for example python3.7 and win64 should use mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl).

Then run this command:

```
python -m pip install C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop\mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```