# Python error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, astropy

I have a problem installing an additional package to Python Anaconda using pip in the Anaconda Prompt:

```
pip install --upgrade pyregion
```

The error I get is:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Other packages such as aplpy and pyparsing have installed properly after some initial problems with PATH for the cl.exe file.

I'm using Python Anaconda3 (64-bit) on Windows 10 x64.

The only suggestions i've found have been specific to other packages/modules. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377777/python-error-command-microsoft-visual-studio-10-0-vc-bin-cl-exe-failed) will help you out ;)

Comment: Yeah i've been trying solutions in that post but so far no luck :/ I'll go through it again though!

Comment: Solved multiple errors by adding file directories to an INCLUDE system variable but have come up with a new error which I can't seem to fix: 

    `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
    14.0\\VC\\bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by simply reinstalling Visual C++ and Anaconda since I just got stuck with new errors. Works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling python3.8  new version and removing the old it workes perfect for me try it.