# Install requirements.txt with pip for Python 2 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, requirements.txt

I am trying to install remote environment like on remote server using requirements.txt.

So first I went to Server went to virtualenv by

`source bin/activate` and typed:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

then on my Windows machine I run:

```
pip2 install -r requirements.txt
```

I have currently Python27 on Server and Windos machine.

This is output on my Windows 8:

```
Collecting Cap1xxx==0.1.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached Cap1xxx-0.1.3.tar.gz
Collecting ExplorerHAT==0.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached ExplorerHAT-0.4.2.tar.gz
Collecting Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz
Collecting Jinja2==2.7.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached Jinja2-2.7.3.tar.gz
Collecting MarkupSafe==0.23 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
Collecting Pillow==2.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Using cached Pillow-2.6.1-cp27-none-win32.whl
Collecting ................. and so on


Collecting urllib3==1.9.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 43))
  Using cached urllib3-1.9.1-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv==15.1.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 44))
Collecting wheel==0.24.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 45))
  Using cached wheel-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wsgiref==0.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 46))
  Using cached wsgiref-0.1.2.zip
Collecting RPi.GPIO (from Cap1xxx==0.1.3->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached RPi.GPIO-0.6.3.tar.gz
Collecting PyOpenSSL (from ndg-httpsclient==0.3.2->-r requirements.txt (line 22))
Collecting and everything is fine
.............................
```

And then there is a traceback:

```
Running setup.py install for RPi.GPIO ... error
        Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\3c8a~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-tvvec2\\RPi.GPIO\\setup.py';f=
    getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\3c8a~1\appdata\local\temp\pip
    -kql53i-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win32-2.7
        creating build\lib.win32-2.7\RPi
        copying RPi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\RPi
        creating build\lib.win32-2.7\RPi\GPIO
        copying RPi\GPIO\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\RPi\GPIO
        running build_ext
        building 'RPi._GPIO' extension
        creating build\temp.win32-2.7
        creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
        creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\source
        C:\Users\Иван\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcsourc
    e/py_gpio.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\source/py_gpio.obj
        py_gpio.c
        source/py_gpio.c(87) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
        source/py_gpio.c(200) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
        source/py_gpio.c(227) : warning C4047: 'return' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
        source/py_gpio.c(345) : error C2373: 'output' : redefinition; different type modifiers
                c:\users\Ёў -\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-tvvec2\rpi.gpio\source\constants.h(29) : see declaration of 'output'
        source/py_gpio.c(345) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
        source/py_gpio.c(359) : warning C4047: 'return' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
        error: command 'C:\\Users\\\xc8\xe2\xe0\xed\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
Cap1xxx==0.1.3
ExplorerHAT==0.4.2
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pillow==2.6.1
Werkzeug==0.9.6
argparse==1.2.1
automationhat==0.0.4
blinker==1.3
blinkt==0.1.0
chardet==2.3.0
colorama==0.3.2
drumhat==0.0.5
envirophat==0.0.6
fourletterphat==0.0.2
html5lib==0.999
itsdangerous==0.24
microdotphat==0.1.3
mote==0.0.3
motephat==0.0.2
ndg-httpsclient==0.3.2
numpy==1.8.2
phatbeat==0.0.2
pianohat==0.0.5
picamera==1.13
picraft==1.0
piglow==1.2.4
pyasn1==0.1.7
pyserial==2.6
rainbowhat==0.0.2
requests==2.4.3
scrollphat==0.0.7
scrollphathd==1.0.1
sense-emu==1.0
sense-hat==2.2.0
six==1.8.0
skywriter==0.0.7
sn3218==1.2.7
spidev==3.0
touchphat==0.0.1
twython==3.1.2
urllib3==1.9.1
virtualenv==15.1.0
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I do not understand this traceback and how to handle this....

Maybe because at the beginning I tried to install dependencies using file getting from Server not being in vertualenv.. And some traces remain in cache, but when I clean cache of pip nothing changes.

So what is the problem here and how to handle it?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT ONE:**

The problem is that RPI.gpio is only for linux machine (for Raspberry Pi to be more exact) and I am trying to install it on Windows.

So should I somehow to clean /tmp or cache...?

Comment: check if this post helps - https://stackoverflow.com/q/36377777/2650427

Comment: There are packages which are not compilable in windows in your case.Create a virtual env in Raspberry Pi,Install all packages there.Then
copy site-packages folder from Raspberry Pi & paste it in Site-Packages directory on windows.This should work.

Comment: @AshishBainade no it won't, there is a reason why it does not work on windows. Besides, it has a compiled C backend, which will simply not work on an OS other than what it was compiled on

Answer (score 1):

There are packages which are not compilable in windows in your case.Create a virtualenv in Raspberry Pi,Install all packages there.Then copy site-packages folder from Raspberry Pi & paste it in Site-Packages directory on windows.This should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is easy way in your case as I can see. You have implemented some packages which is not capable for running on Windows machine, like RpiGpio. So just remove them from your requirements list and get it done.