# error: command after pip install prophet failed with exit status 2 -

Tags: python, installation, pip, anaconda, anomaly-detection

I'm trying to install prophet module with pip install prophet and I get this error:

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\roman\anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3atf7x8i\\prophet_b4d79ec5b1364530badc909dc352ecb0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Roman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3atf7x8i\\prophet_b4d79ec5b1364530badc909dc352ecb0\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3wqyamtb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\roman\anaconda\Include\prophet' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm really stuck and don't know what to do

thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible Duplicate?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377777/python-error-command-microsoft-visual-studio-10-0-vc-bin-cl-exe-failed

Comment: no this is for sql

Comment: Please post the full error message. The line you have posted is just saying that the compiler had an error. It is impossible to know from that what went wrong. Please also state your python version

Comment: I tried on all the version 3.7 till 3.10 and still not working